# Can I bind something else than 'this' for a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to pass outside variable to jQuery Ajax's success-function. My ajax is in a loop like so:

```
var props = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var results = 
{
    a: null,
    b: null,
    c: null
};

for(var key in props)
{
    var prop = props[key];

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'someurl',

        data:
        {
            somedata: 'somevalue'
        },

        success: function(data, status, xhr)
        {
            // This here does not work properly, because the prop's value changes
            // Due to promise stuff
            results[prop] = data;  
        }
    });
}
```

I need to stuff the data returned in success in to the correct place, but the implementation above does not work because the value of `prop` changes before the success is called.

I found out that I can "bypass" this problem by binding the success-function's this with the prop like so:

```
success: function(data, status, xhr)
{
    results[this] = data;  
}.bind(prop)
```

But this does not seem like a very good idea and besides, I can only bind one variable, not multiple if need be.

This  does not seem to work either:

```
success: function(data, status, xhr)
{
    var privprop = prop;
    results[privprop] = data;  
}
```

So basically what is the best way to give each success callback a "private" variable, which value is what the value of prop was when the whole ajax was made? Can I somehow bind multiple variables and overwrite something else than `this`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to limit the scope of every `prop` variable for a specific ajax by doing something like this:

```
for(var key in props)
{
    var prop = props[key];

    (function(prop){


        $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'someurl',

            data:
            {
                somedata: 'somevalue'
            },

            success: function(data, status, xhr)
            {
                // This here does not work properly, because the prop's value changes
                // Due to promise stuff
                results[prop] = data;  
            }
        });
    })(prop);
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, http://jsfiddle.net/nyq01ysk/.

Comment: Yeah.. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Can you talk about: What's the technique name you are using: `(function(prop){..........})(prop)`

Comment: @Mr.Wolf It is called Immediately-invoked Function Expression (IIFE): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Comment: @Void Thank you. I forgot I could use IIFE for that (:

Comment: @void By the way, is the bind/apply method I was using a horrible mistake? Is it ok to use it if I only need to pass a sigle variable like in my example?

Comment: OOfcourse you can do that but in your code prop inside the bind will be out of scope. So no good to use it.